# Drawable with selector?

Tags: android, image, selector, drawable, touch-event

in drawable folder:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/icon2" /> 
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon3" /> 
 </selector>
```

and the layout is just simple linear layout that fill the whole space

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/on_touch_"
    android:weightSum="1" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

and when I press this nothing happens

If I add, for example, some textview and assign `android:background="@drawable/on_touch_"` then that textview when pressed it changes the image correctly.

Where is the problem with the linear layout why it does not change the image when pressed ?

Edit:
I am sure that my drawable selector is good and working cause I put as a background to other elements and it is working.

But my problem is how to set the drawable to the **root** element

Comment: What you want to implement exactly?

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your layout :

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

This will set the pressed state when you'll click it.

Answer (score 0):

try out

save_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/save_hover_new" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/save_hover_new" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/save_hover_new" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/save_new" />

</selector>
```

and give layout's background as selector like
android:background="@drawable/save_selector

Comment: tnx, but the problem is not in the selector. I put the same selector drawable to other component like textview and it works but it doesn't with layout

Comment: YES, definitely it can be done ! I have done it, but not on the root layout, my problem is that I can't add it on the root layout

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure I do not have a drawable namesake. You seem to be using `on_touch_.xml` as your selector. Is there perhaps also an `on_touch_.png`?

I would also make sure that I am not setting the background again, to something else, or making it unclickable, in code.

Answer (score 0):

I got a selector in a root element that is working fine; the background switches when pressed. It is not the root element of the activity layout, but it is the root element of the XML file.

The background is assigned with a png at first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/panel"
>
    ...
```

I assign the background to the selector only when assigning an OnClickListener:

```
private void setClickListener(OnClickListener ocl) {

    View boxRoot = findViewById(R.id.box_root);
    if (ocl != null) {
        boxRoot.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        boxRoot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.panel_arrow_right_bgstate));

        setClickable(true); 
                    ...
```

In my XML, I used `android:clickable="true"` but then I also added `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to match your case. That also worked fine, with background switching for all my four states.

```
// panel_arrow_right_bgstate.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/panel_arrow_right_normal"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/panel_arrow_right_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/panel_arrow_right_selected"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/panel_arrow_right_pressed"/>
```

If this is not working for you, something else is wrong with your code, somewhere else.

When I add or remove drawables, Eclipse sometimes gets fishy and mix them up. My normal measurements are:

1. Clean project
2. Refresh res folder in Eclipse
3. Delete gen\com.comp.proj\R.java